# Matrix of transformation for reflections

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find two matrices of transformations from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$:

reflection over $x=y$

reflection over $y=z$

how do I do this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 user localhost? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note under $T:$ reflection over $x=y$ $$(1,0,0)\mapsto(0,1,0)$$

[image]

i.e. $$T(1,0,0)=0(1,0,0)+1(0,1,0)+0(0,0,1)$$

The calculation of the images of the other standard basis elements viz. $(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ are similar.

Comment: thanks for this, that picture is great. then $T(0,1,0) = (1,0,0)$ and $T(0,0,1) = (0,0,1)$

Comment: and with that I can get a matrix for x=y! If I knew how to write matrices in latex, I would do it here. :(

Comment: im going ot make my own picture like this in my head and find a matrix for y=z.

Comment: okay, here's my understanding for the y=z plane:

$T(1,0,0) = 1,0,0$ since the x axis is perpendicular to the y-z plane.




$T(0,1,0) = (0,0,1)$



$T(0,0,1) = (0,1,0)$

Comment: if I compose these two reflections, what sort of transformation do i get?

Comment: @terribleatmath: that's write! To evaluate the composition simply apply the second transformation on the image of the first e.g. reflection over $x=y$ will take $(1,0,0)$ to $(0,1,0)$ and reflection over $y=z$ will take $(0,1,0)$ to $(0,0,1).$ So for the composition reflection over $x=y$ followed by reflection over $y=z,$$$(1,0,0)\mapsto(0,0,1).$$ Apply the same process for $(0,1,0),(0,0,1).$

Answer (score 0):

Given a unit vector $u$ perpendicular to the axis of reflection, the transformation T given by $T(x)=x-2(x\cdot u)u$ Is the reflection.

Rewriting that in terms of matrix multiplication, you have

$T(x)=x(I-2u^\top u)$ where x and u are row vectors.

This is exactly the Householder transformation user127.0.0 mentioned.

Start by finding the appropriate unit perpendiculars and try it out!